# How I can iterate over Pandas rows without repetition?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I want to iterate over a Pandas Dataframe relation each row from the other rows in the Dataframe. I have something like this but I think this can be improved.

```
user_dict = dict()
nfollower_dict = dict()
df_hashtag_dict = df_hashtag.to_dict('record')
for di in df_hashtag_dict:
  node_1 = di['username']
  for dj in df_hashtag_dict:
    node_2 = dj['username']
       if node_1 != node_2:
         if (node_1 + "-" + node_2) in user_dict.keys():
            user_dict[node_1 + "-" + node_2] = user_dict.get(node_1 + "-" + node_2) + di['p'] + dj['p']
         elif (node_2 + "-" + node_1) in user_dict.keys():
            user_dict[node_2 + "-" + node_1] = user_dict.get(node_1 + "-" + node_2) + di['p'] + dj['p']
         else:
            user_dict[node_1 + "-" + node_2] = di['p'] + dj['p']
            nfollower_dict[di['username']] = di['num_followers']
            nfollower_dict[dj['username']] = dj['num_followers']
```

I want to know if there is a way to delete all nested if/else, and if there is an efficient way to iterate over the dataframe without repetition.

The Dataframe has three columns: username, num_followers, p.

I want to iterate and save the result like this:
(john-miki: 34 + 42 , john-rick : 34 + 10 , ...)

The problem I have is that john-miki and miki-john isn't the same key in Python but the real relation is that. I want to get a key in common between these two keys.

Also I want to iterate avoiding repitions like john-john, john-miki, john-rick, ..., miki-john, miki-miki.

Input:

```
username  num_followers      p 
john           76            34
miki           10            42
rick           200           10
```

An output will be:

```
user_dict = {
 "john-miki": 34 + 42,
 "john-rick": 34 + 10,
  ...
}
nfollower_dict = {
 "john": 50,
 "miki": 10,
  ...
 }
```

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you added an example and the expected output IMHO.

Comment: I edited the question with an output example. Thanks :)

Comment: Input data is important to understand your problem. Try `print(df_hashtag.head(5).to_string(index=False))`